# How to make a pointer to a function and define some arguments to this function in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arguments, function-pointers

I would like to do something like this:

```
int a(int a, int b)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 2;
    int (*b)(int) = a(a = n);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to achieve it because I want to be able to pass a function as argument to another function but with some values defined.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)/[lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: `int (*b)(int) = [](int b) { return a(2, b); };`

Comment: BTW, you should use distinct and descriptive names.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, but if I want to capture a variable it doesn't work.

int n = 2;
int (*b)(int) = [n](int b) { return a(n, b); };

Comment: In that case, make it `auto b = ...;` It won't be a plain function pointer anymore (it can't be, for the simple practical reason that there's no space in the plain function pointer to also store captured values).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your other function is this:

```
using func_ptr_t = int(*)(int);

void other_func(func_ptr_t f) {
    f(3);
}
```

Then you can use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to bind one of the parameters:

```
int foo(int a, int b) // dont use same name for function and its argument
{
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    auto f = [](int b){ return foo(2,b); };
    other_func(f);
}
```

If you want to capture the paramter to bind you cannot convert the lambda to a function pointer. Functions don't have state. One options is to make `other_func` a template:

```
template <typename F>
void other_func(F f) { f(3); }
int foo(int a, int b) { return 0; }

int main() {
    int n = 2;
    auto f = [n](int b){ return foo(n,b); };
    other_func(f);
}
```

However, now different instantations of `other_func` are different functions. Sometimes this isn't desired, then you need some form of type erasure, for example via `std::function<int(int)>`.

Comment: `other_func()` does not need to be a template for this example to work, eg: `void other_func(int (*f)(int)) { f(3); }` Let's not confuse the issue by mixing multiple language features together when the OP asked about one specific thing.

Comment: @RemyLebau does not need to, but it also doesn't hurt. Well, maybe it does. Depends. Added the non template version

Comment: @RemyLebeau "lets focus on one language feature at a time" completely agreed

Comment: I'd say the template version is much better because it's more general. Using the function pointer version, you can't pass `x` instead of `2` (where `x` is some local variable).

Comment: If I capture a value it doesn't work. int n = 3; int (*p)(int) = [n](int b){ return foo(n,b); };

Comment: @Mart you didn't ask for capture so my answer doesn't show how to capture. There is not one solution that fits all. Make other_func a template, but then it is not one function. Let it take a std::function, but then you pay for type erasure. Please clarify, the question. (Though I'll be afk for some time)